# Webdriver Xpath link issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me getting Xpath for the below

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
some more code here

    <a href="/https/<IP>/perl/cbhftp?sid=e18559a31a7320f326da0da8d66cb93f;src_frame=query;tgt_frame=response;mpath=0201" target="response">
```

I am new to webdriver and want to automate by clicking on link.

Comment: Please put the entire html document code the div is located in.

Comment: Can't paste complete code as space is less. Can you tell how to paste code in comments?

Comment: just the structure, for example: "<html><div style="white-space: nowrap;">text</div><div  style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="url"></a></div></html>

Comment: Don't paste it in a comment, but edit the question!

Answer (score 1):

It will be better when you learn how to easily  find xpath by yourself.
You can use e.g.[firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) - a firefox extension.

[Here](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php) you have some simple tutorial.

For Xpath finding you can download additional [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) extension - you will have additional tab on firebug

Comment: We want to automate some event for this website. It is quite secure and stopped external plugins. We want to do this to download more then 100 files from this

Comment: As Wasafa1 mentioned - you can use "inspect element' functionality. e.g.in IE it's in Developers toolbar (F12) - it shouldn't be restricted.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[1]/a[7]"));
I tried by getting this xpath from chrome, but don't knwo how to use this ."/html/body/form/div[1]/a[7]" is xpath i got . IS the above code ok?

Comment: That will be against the policies of our workplace. div 1 tab contains many links where i want to go with with one of them .

Comment: @user3091446 if you cannot provide the code neither I or dear siemic cannot help you reproduce the error or to find an element in a web page we cannot test..

Comment: @user3091446 - in Chrome - right click on the page, select 'inspect element'. In the source code displayed in the panel find your node, right click on it and chose "Copy XPath" - and you can paste it into notepad - that shouldn't be against any policy ;)

Comment: /html/body/form/div[1]/a[7] this is the XPATH I provided. It's from same website

Answer (score 0):

It will be much simpler if you add "id" field into the div element that way you could use:

```
browser.findElement(By.ID("TheDiv\Href idName")).Click())
```

Other option (if you are not yet conviced about the first one), is to open the page in Chrome (or any other browser), make a RIGHT CLICK on the element, and choose "inspect element", than you have an option to see the XPath for it.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[1]/a[7]"));
I tried above
Xpah I got from chrome browser as you told but not working . Is there any other way to write this code?

Comment: if it works for you - great :)
I still think it will be better for automation to use a stronger identifier.
For example, if you add another div above - this specifier will no longer work.

But if you go by ID, it is more change resistant.

Comment: It is not working . I doubt if i wrote code correctly. Is this the correct way to write?
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[1]/a[7]"));

Comment: your selenium syntax is correct, can you paste the entire HTML page?